# Select oldest toggled class after a certain amount have been toggled

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope and want to make a grid of square elements that enlarge to a bigger size when clicked. This is all fine, however I want to make sure that only a certain amount of elements are enlarged at any one time. So, for example, if 3 is the maximum allowed then when a fourth is clicked the first element that was enlarged is shrunk again.

Is there any obvious jQuery method of tracking this, or indeed something within Isotope? I can count the elements using

```
$('.large-element').length;
```

But I don't know of any obvious way of keeping track of the order in which the classes were toggled. I'm guessing an array would be a decent solution too but I'm pretty hopeless with JS arrays.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of tracking the item clicks with a JS array:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var largeArr = [];

            $(document).ready( function() {

                $("div.item").click( function() {
                    if (largeArr.length == 3) {
                        largeArr[0].removeClass("item-large");
                        largeArr.shift();  
                    }
                    var item = $(this).addClass("item-large");                                                
                    largeArr.push(item); 
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .item-large {
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Item 3</div>
        <div class="item">Item 4</div>
        <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwatts1980/Sqazu) of it in action.

Comment: thanks for this. it's not flawless, if you click an element multiple times it adds that to the array multiple times, and ideally clicking an element at any time would close it regardless of its position in the array. I think doing this flawlessly is surprisingly complex the more I investigate!